# Turn off SSL for every page except login.php and register.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

# Turn SSL off for everything except login.php (register.php)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The code above is used to turn SSL (https://) off for every page except login.php. How can I add register.php page, so I will have https:// protocol enabled on both login.php and register.php pages? I tried duplicating this line

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/login\.php [NC]
**RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/register\.php [NC]**
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both login and register in the same condition

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(login|register)\.php [NC]
```