# How to use .htaccess to disable SSL off for all pages except two? (login.php, register.php)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess Problem - ( Turn off SSL for every page except login.php and register.php )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189484/htaccess-problem-turn-off-ssl-for-every-page-except-login-php-and-register-p)

I have SSL enabled on all my website, but I only need it on two pages **login.php** and **register.php**, How can I disable it on all pages except these two? So when I redirect say from login.php to home page, I don't want eny warnings etc.

Thank You

Comment: Better build your links properly in first place: see the strategy in first part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133599/redirect-http-to-https-for-one-page/7133731#7133731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All modern browsers will display a warning if you leave a secure connection, so as soon as you've switched to HTTPS you should not switch back if you don't want a warning.

To switch to HTTPS for those two page use something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^register.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For more examples see [HERE](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-ssl-in-htaccess-examples.html).

Comment: These rules are incorrect: 1) rewrite condition will only be applied to first rewrite rule; 2) It will be redirected to the website root folder and not to the same page on secure protocol; 3) it will not disable HTTPS (switch to http) for all other URLs.

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks, I've fixed 1&2, but 3 is on purpose as stated above...

Comment: Cool. One more thing -- if this rule will be placed in .htaccess (OP has .htaccess tag) these rules will not trigger the rewrite -- URL in htaccess starts relative to the folder, so no leading slash: remove it or make it optional.

Comment: alright I tried combining two post's together, soo is this right?         
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

#Turn ssl on login.php and register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^register.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Turn ssl off except login.php and register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^login.php(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^register.php(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Seems right to me, but just try it...