# htaccess set http on all pages except login page

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

I used an example from another Stack post to force http on my site for all pages except for a user login page. I don't know if I am missing anything, but this did not work:

```
# Turn SSL on for login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^customer/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^customer/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That looks like it should work, but for some reason it isn't. Can someone please let me know what I am missing. Thank you.

Comment: Are all requests directed to your server directly or are you using a CDN like CloudFlare?

Comment: Please try to convert it like this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202472/how-to-use-htaccess-to-disable-ssl-off-for-all-pages-except-two-login-php-re. marked answer

Comment: The form action on that page goes to a third party, but the action is set as https://sample.com/action

Comment: I'm going to try that post with the marked answer to see if that works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REQUEST_URI` requires a leading slash. So as you have it, it will not match. Try your rules this way.

```
# Turn SSL on for login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I had tried that with a leading slash, but it caused a redirect loop on the login landing page. Forcing http on the other pages worked fine though.

Comment: @Robert the rules work fine for me. Make sure you clear your cache or try in another browser.

Comment: The leading slash makes most sense to me, since that was working on my other rewrite rules, I just didn't know why it was causing the loop on that particular page. Removing the leading slash just made the page behave like the rest of the site and force http. I will try this, thank you very much.