# how should i exclude certain .php URLs from being loaded through SSL?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl

recently i activated flexible SSL on my wordpress website,but i wish to load certain .php URLs through simple http, ones like: thankyou.php and contact.php ,and a few others,

Comment: Could you please explain, what you have done so far and where you are stuck currently? At the moment, it is not that clear what your asking for and what your problem is.

Comment: how should i exclude such URLs from being loaded through SSL?now all my site loads through SSL, the ones like : domain/contact.php and domain/thankyou.php do you know any .htaccess code i can add for this reason,

Comment: put another way: i don't want domain/contact.php and a couple of other .php URLs to be loaded through SSL, the web server is apache, i know i should add a couple of codes to .htaccess to exclude such URLs, but how? what is that code?

Comment: I do not have any knowledge on the field of servers or apache at all. However, you might ask your question on ServerFault since there could be more experts on this field. If so, please delete this question in order to prevent cross-posting.

Comment: my question is very similar to this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206287/htaccess-how-to-set-ssl-on-certain-pages-script-needs-modifying